# ul li border bottom is NOT full width

Tags: html, css

I am very sorry if this question might be duplicated a lot. But I've done a lot of searching about this question but still cannot find a solution. How can I make ul li border-bottom full width?

[image]

```css
body {
 background: blue;
}


.Table .Content {
  background: #fff;
  color: #fefeff;
}

.Table .Content ul {
  padding: 15px 20px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.Table .Content ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="Table">
        <div class="Content">
          <ul>

            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any of the response will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is full width, of the `<li>` element.

Comment: @ChrisPickford No, the `<li>` element is not full width. Try to add `background-color`, and you can see the difference. Run the snippet that I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to give 'left/right' padding to `li` instead of `ul`

```css
.Table .Content {
  background: #fff;
  color: #fefeff;
}

.Table .Content ul {
  padding: 15px 0px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-position:inside;
}

.Table .Content ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="Table">
        <div class="Content">
          <ul>

            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP can set it using `list-style-position:inside;`

Comment: You should have mentioned this in your answer.

Comment: also maybe mention what's causing the issue: ul's have a default padding styling

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Table .Content {
  background: #fff;
  color: #fefeff;
}

.Table .Content ul {
  padding: 15px 20px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.Table .Content ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  color: #000;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="Table">
        <div class="Content">
          <ul>

            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper at sapien ut accumsan. Fusce consequat nec eros vel suscipit. Vestibulum sit amet ornare erat, sed porttitor metus.</li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added this to li: list-style-position: inside.